# How to span a one of the grandchild element to 100% width in CSS Grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

How to span a one of the grandchild element to 100% width in CSS Grid while the parent is container is divided into 3 fractions.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}
.container > div {
  background-color: #4834d4;
  width: 100%;
}
.container > div .child_01 {
  background-color: #f9ca24;
  width: 80%;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 1rem auto;
}
.container > div .child_02 {
  background-color: #eb4d4b;
  width: 80%;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 1rem auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div>
  <div class="child_01"></div>
  <div class="child_02"></div>
 </div>
 <div>
  <div class="child_01"></div>
  <div class="child_02"></div>
 </div>
 <div>
  <div class="child_01"></div>
  <div class="child_02"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

What I am trying to achieve is this.[desired layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yyJ8.png)

Is this possible to achieve in CSS Grid.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @TannerDolby I have tried spanning the column for the grandchild but that seems not working.

Comment: @Sagar You need to change the approach bit, need to follow row concept. First row should have 3 container with width: 33% each, next 3 consecutive row should have 100% width.

Comment: If changing the html is not an option then you can't do it.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with a solution

```css
.container {
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #4834d4;
}

.container > div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
.child_01 {
  display: inline-flex;
  background-color: #f9ca24;
  width: 30%;
  height: 50px;
}

.child_02 {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #eb4d4b;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 1rem auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <div class="child_01"></div>
    <div class="child_01"></div>
    <div class="child_01"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="child_02"></div>
  <div class="child_02"></div>
  <div class="child_02"></div>
</div>
```

I have use flex instead of grid.